# Is any class considered a Context in android or is there something specific that must be done?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, android-context

I have this class, omitting the code to make it more readable:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class TimeTrackerActivity extends Activity {

    //some code here
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.times_list);

    listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);

    TimeTrackerOpenHelper openHelper = new TimeTrackerOpenHelper(this);
    //my error with line of code right above saying
    //the constructor of TimeTrackerOpenHelper(TimeTrackerActivity) is undefined

    }
    //more code here
}
```

I commented where my error is. I have looked at other example online and everyone else is sending this in to the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, which leads me to assume that it should be working. But its not. My code is as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class TimeTrackerOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "timetracker.db", null, 1);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {/*stuff*/}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase datbase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {/*stuff*/}

}
```

Is my assumption wrong and is there something I am missing.

Comment: you probably need to make the TimeTrackerOpenHelper constructor public.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Activity` derives from `android.content.Context`, your code should compile without an error, as long as the `Context` class used by `TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context)` is also an `android.content.Context`, and not a `Context` class from a different package.

**EDIT**

Thanks to superfell's comment, I think the problem is the visibility of `TimeTrackerOpenHelper`'s constructor. Try making it public:

```
public TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context) {
```

Comment: Thats what I am saying. I don't know why it won't get rid of the error. As you can see I am extending from Activity, and I am sending in the right thing... but I can't figure out the reason. But I appreciate the quick hint on Context.

Comment: Can you post the `import` statements of the file that defines `TimeTrackerOpenHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

Android Activity is a subclass of Context. See [Activity source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Activity.java). And no, not every class is considered a Context in Android. You have to extend Context but i don't think you would want to perform such a thing and need to.

Comment: I should not need to. I have seen tutorials use this, and they all send the this through to it, and it works just fine. For some reason its giving me this error, making me confused on why this is happening.

Comment: I tried to compile and run same source code with your example, however received no errors. It is impossible to help with this perspective. Is it possible for you to share full source code?

Answer (score 0):

No the only "class" that contains a context reference are Activities and Services.
If you use for example a BroadcastReceiver you receive in your listener method the context reference.